# What kind of product is this?

Tags: product, configurable-product, products-management, grouped-products

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm trying to figure out, what kind of pruduct this one is:
[Product](http://www.mayoral.com/es/espana/botin-de-piel-casual-ese1-14-42460-016--5)

If you'll click on the color it takes you to another product... With diferent image gallery, but the same sizes and it also maintains the colors available. So I suppose these product's are linked somehow. How to achieve that?

Is this somekind of Grouped configurable product or what?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

That would be similar to Simple Configurable Products in Magento:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Comment: Ok then, how do I activate so when I choose the color to display a `media_gallery` of the selected color?

Comment: That is an available option in Simple Configurable Products - You set up the main product, then each of the various simple products. In the configuration you can choose to have the image change, the whole gallery change, the description to change, etc.

Comment: I highly recommend getting the Simple Configurable Products extension from the Github repo, and NOT the Magento Connect site.  The Github version has some important bugfixes and patches that the Magento Connect version is missing: https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Comment: Does it work on CE 1.9?

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas - yes it does